# Appending 2 dimensional slices in Go

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, go

I have a couple 2 dimensional slices in my Go program and I want to join them together.

However, `append()` doesn't take this type.

`cannot use myArray (type [][]string) as type []string in append`

How do you append multi-dimensional slices using Go in an idiomatic way?

Comment: Nitpick: These are not arrays but slices.

Comment: Also, show your code.  Make it easier for people who want to help you to reproduce the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `...` to pass the second slice as [variadic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) parameters to append. For example:

```
a := [][]string{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}
b := [][]string{{"1", "2"}, {"3", "4"}}
a = append(a, b...)
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/W1AYFLXlT1)